# Typescript typeRoots not detecting the type definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, node-modules, tsconfig

I'm using TypeScript inside my project. If I try to import a package using commonJS

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

Then I don't get any error during compilation, but when I convert it into ES6 module like

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

I get a compilation error like:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid'. 'C:/Users/project/dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/uuid/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try 'npm i --save-dev @types/uuid' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'uuid';

I already installed the @types/uuid.

I do face this issue with packages that need type-definition (@types/*)

If the project structure is something like the below example:

```
├── dependencies
│   └── nodejs
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── node_modules
│       └── package-lock.json
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── .gitignore
```

To regenerate this issue, run the commands mentioned below:

```bash
$ mkdir project
$ cd project
$ touch tsconfig.json
```

add following json to tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",                       
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
        "baseUrl": "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",
    "typeRoots": ["./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["dependencies", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

```bash
$ mkdir dependencies/nodejs
$ mkdir src/models
$ cd dependencies/nodejs
$ npm init
$ npm i uuid
$ npm i -D @types/uuid typescript
$ cd ..
$ cd ..
$ cd src/models
$ touch index.ts
$ nano index.ts
```

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'; // inline typescript error (same mentioned in the issue)
console.log(uuid());
```

uuid does support ESM modules and I did create an [issue](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/668) on uuid github. I finally found out that if package.json exists in the root of the project, I will never have to deal with such an issue.

Example:

```
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── dist (or build
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json 
└── .gitignore
```

I only face the issue with packages that need type-definition (@types/*) when use nested structured project (where package.json file isn't available in the root directory).

The project structure is based on using AWS Lambda with layers for serverless applications. And this "dependencies" folder is basically a layer and AWS-lambda layers are defined with such a structure as

> dependencies/nodejs/package.json

Therefore, package.json should not be placed at the root of the project.

However, I believe this is not a package issue but rather a typescript TSconfig issue.

I tried to define typeRoots in tsconfig file but its not working.

Here is the github repository that contain sample project that generates the issue:

> https://github.com/sulemanelahi/typescript-type-definition

I want to use ES6 Modules for importing uuid in nested structure project same as I shared.

Comment: Looks like the `uuid` package does some special stuff for ESM modules. This is either a bug in that package, or in the@types/uuid package. Open a ticket

Comment: of note: there is no "ES5 style" or "ES6 style", period. The `require` option is called the CommonJS (or CJS) module system and the `import` one is ECMA modules (or ESM, or ES6 modules).

Comment: @Evert no its not a bug, I already create an [issue](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/668) on the uuid github and findout that the issue isn't with the package. But with the file structure.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json, why do you still have "`"module": "commonjs"`" if you are trying to change to ECMAScript imports? Shouldn't it be ["module": "ES6"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)? Also, this seems like a strange setup. Can you give a brief explanation of why you put dependencies in `:/dependencies/nodejs/node_modules` instead of `:/node_modules`? Please [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding paths property:

```
"baseUrl": "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",    
"paths": {
  "uuid": ["./@types/uuid"]
}
```

TypeRoots define the path for global types. This basically indicates the .d.ts file contains declare module syntax, while packages (of type definitions) like @types/UUID do not.

**UPDATE:** I used @Andrew Allen's solution, which he mentioned in the comment section below his answer that he got from [this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-369783776) (Andrew didn't update it in the answer).

This is also resolve the issue and Its better rather writing each type definition package path.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5"
        "baseUrl": "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",
        "paths": {
            "*" : ["*"]
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 }  from 'uuid/index';
```

Reasoning:

Running

```
tsc --traceResolution
```

had trace

```
File '.../dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types/uuid.ts' does not exist.
File '.../dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types/uuid.tsx' does not exist.
File '.../dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types/uuid.d.ts' does not exist.
```

Extending this logic putting

```
"typeRoots": ["dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types/**/index.d.ts"],
```

allows going back to

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 }  from 'uuid';
```

UPDATE: I had also set

```
"baseUrl": "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types"
```

which allows

```
"typeRoots": ["**/*.d.ts"],
```

Comment: Here is the github repo that I created to generate the issue:
[Github Repo Link](https://github.com/sulemanelahi/typescript-type-definition)
By the way the above solution isn't working with current tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Ah, I changed some settings (module, moduleResolution) as I went along and once it started working changed them back to yours. Maybe I needed to reset typescript server to fully verify. It might be a few days but I’ll do this again and confirm.

Comment: @SulemanElahi turns out I'd added /@types to baseUrl, see update.

Comment: Yeah, It does works but then other packages that don't have /@types (type definitions). Will not work.

Comment: ah ok. i've just tried [this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-369783776) and that seems to work with the following in paths `"*" : ["./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types/*"]` in paths and allowing `"baseUrl": "./"`

Comment: It works but then I have a question about why `typeRoots` isn't working and `paths` is working

Comment: Not sure, that GitHub link has more info but I understand typeRoots isn’t really intended to be used

Comment: TypeRoots for global types contain declare module syntax, while packages like UUID have declaration files (.d.ts) without declare module syntax.

TypeRoots cannot detect types of packages like UUID because declaration files do not contain declare module syntax

Comment: To use paths property the * adds conflicts with other packages so I add uuid something like:
`"uuid": [./node_modules/@types/uuid]`